# Wordpress Redirect to login

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, redirect

I'm making a site with WordPress as the CMS (installed on our server, not WordPress.com). I want the account page to redirect to the login page if the user isn't logged in. There's a custom template for the account page (account.php) and at the top I've placed this code:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect('www.mypage.com/login');
    die();
}
```

When I update and save the account.php page, I go into the WordPress dashboard and update the page there too. When I go to view the account page (either by refreshing the page or clicking "view page") it usually redirects the first time to the login page. Yay! All seems well, except when I click the account link, I expect it to take me to the login page as I'm still not logged in, but it takes me to the account page anyway... I've tried in InCognito mode to be sure I'm not logged in. I put an echo inside that if statement, and it reaches it just fine, so I know that it's correctly detecting that I'm not logged in.

Does anyone know why it's redirecting on first load but not again when navigating back to that page? How can I make it so it's impossible to view account.php until logged in?

Answer (score 0):

the above should be like

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect('www.mypage.com/login');
    die();
}
```

you are missing out the is_user_logged_in**()**.

check those bracks its a function ;)

Comment: Sorry I freehand typed my post, I didn't have a syntax error in the real deal.

Comment: then it is_user_logged_in() should work perfectly. your above code is 100%. unless you have some other issue. it might be the permalink you are using to redirect. is your code at the top of the template. please post your actuall code that you are fetching the redirect URL.

Comment: The issue isn't that user_logged_in is not working, the issue is that the redirect IS working, but only once. I'm not sure if I phrased that correctly.

Comment: Have you checked the cookies and made sure there isn't any still floating around when logged out?